# How to get Unicode character of a numeric value in Tcl (JIM TCL)

Tags: tcl

for some reasons , i need to use [jim tcl](http://jim.tcl.tk/index.html/doc/www/www/index.html) ,
this is what my code looks like :

```
set numbertoconvert 40
if { $numbertoconvert >= 32 } { puts ["A CODE TO GET 40th UNICODE CHARACTER WHICH IS "(""] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`format`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm) with the [`%c`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm#M16) modifier:

```
format %c 40
```